# Link field to views pages and nodes

Tags: 7, views, navigation

On my content type I want to allow a content administrator to insert a hyperlink to a page and allow them to define a list of related pages. This works fine for linking to nodes, but I am unable to get Views Pages to list.

I have tried the following options:

- references module - only allows you to reference nodes
- View reference - Not an interface I want to give to a non-techie
- entityreference - also does not allow you to reference views pages
- viewfield - only allows you to *insert* views and the interface is not end user friendly
- linkit with linkit views - could not get "views pages" to list, documentation seemed to imply it was possible

The items are all in my main menu, is there not a module or picker out there that allows you to pick menu items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linkit + Linkit views *is* a solution, it allows:

- Autocomplete field to look-up Nodes or Views
- WYSIWYG and link field integration
- allows external links too

**Just note**: the autocomplete lookup requires the "Display name" of your view to be descriptive, as it is used for the lookup not the title, if these are all "Page" you will not find them.

---

What it is not is a node-reference or entity reference, but all I wanted was to have hyperlinks to other nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [View Reference](http://drupal.org/project/viewreference) ?
Please refer to this [page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36190/how-to-insert-a-view-in-the-body-field-of-a-node)

Comment: Thanks, sorry it was not listed above but it is another interface that I simply could not give to a content manager with arguments.